# Is it possible to crack the password.key or any other .key file from /data/system/?

Tags: screen, encryption

I am a newbie...
So this question came in my mind when I removed my screen lock using adb by deleting the .key file from the /data/system/ folder....
For removing we delete the .key file, but what if we copy the .key file to our local PC using adb command and then try to brute force the encryption of the .key file using hashcat (like what we do when cracking the .cap file to get the WiFi password). Also we can use a wordlist.
If we can do this then we can easily brute force PIN screen lock because it has the limited range of possible number combinations.
I don't know what kind of encryption method is used for encrypting the plain password/pin for android screen lock so please answer this.
So please let me know if this is possible....
Also I don't if this is discussed before....

Comment: Please take into account [hardware-backed encryption](https://source.android.com/security/keystore) which cannot be brute forced on or off the device (excluding some hacks).

Comment: That depends on the Android version. For older versions this was possible. But on modern device hardware-backed encryption + GateKeeper makes it hard to do so (I have to admit that I never tried it myself practically).

Comment: Ok So the device I am having is S10+ which has Android 10 not possible...

Comment: @TanmayB definitely not possible. Upcoming devices would save keys in Secure Element (supported since Pie) which is far more secure than the current TEE based hardware storage. So the brute forcing isn't going to work very often.

Comment: Ok Thank You for reacting so fast and letting me know about this @Irfan Latif really thankful to you Bro...